# Can XCode break when data ata memory location changes

Tags: xcode, conditional-breakpoint

Visual Studio has always been able to do this - if you know a mem loc then you can set conditional breakpoints when that mem loc's value changes to a particular value or changes at all.  Is that what Symbolic breakpoints are for in XCode? If so, I cannot see how to do this.

Thx,
Tom

Answer (score 2):

If you're comfortable with gdb, [this question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58851/can-i-set-a-breakpoint-on-memory-access-in-gdb)  should be more than enough to help you out.  If not, you might want to get comfortable with it soon...