# Serious Memory Clash: Variables clashing in C

Tags: c, gcc, gdb

```
    struct Message
{
    char type;
    double idNum;
    char *Time;
    char *asset;
    bool BS;
    float price1;
    int shares1;
    float price2;
    int shares2;        
};
typedef struct Message Message;
struct Asset
        {
            oBook *OrderBook;
            Trade *TradeBook; //will point to the latest trade
            int QtyTraded;
            float ValueTraded;
            char* Time;
        };
typedef struct Asset Asset;
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
    {
        Message* newMessage;
        Asset* Check;
        //manipulation and initialization of Check, so that it holds proper values.

        newMessage = parser("N,2376,01/02/2011 09:15:01.342,JPASSOCIAT FUTSTK 24FEB2011,B,84.05,2000,0,0",newMessage);
    //  MessageProcess(newMessage,AssetMap);
        printf("LAST TRADE ADDRESS %p LAST TRADE TIME %s\n",Check->TradeBook,Check->Time);
    }
    Message*  parser(char *message,Message* new_Message)
    {
        char a[9][256];
        char* tmp =message;
        bool inQuote=0;
        int counter=0;
        int counter2=0;
        new_Message = (Message*)malloc(sizeof(Message));
        while(*tmp!='\0')
        {
            switch(*tmp)
            {
                case ',': if(!inQuote)
                       {    
                        a[counter][counter2]='\0';
                        counter++;
                        counter2=0;
                        }

                      break;
                case '"':
                    inQuote=!inQuote;
                    break;
                default:
                    a[counter][counter2]=*tmp;
                    counter2++;
                    break;
            }
        tmp++;

        }
            a[counter][counter2]='\0';
            new_Message->type = *a[0];
            new_Message->Time  = &a[2][11];
            new_Message->asset = a[3];
            if(*a[4]=='S')
            new_Message->BS = 0;
            else
            new_Message->BS = 1;
            new_Message->price1=atof(a[5]);
            new_Message->shares1=atol(a[6]);
            new_Message->price2=atof(a[7]);
            new_Message->shares2=atol(a[8]);
            new_Message->idNum = atoi(a[1]);
    return(new_Message);
    }
```

Here there is a serious memory clash, in two variables of different scope. I have investigated using gdb and it seems the address of `new_Message->Time` is equalling to the address of `Check->Time`.

**They both are structures of different types** I am trying to resolve this issue, because, when parser changes the value of `new_Message->Time` it manipulates the contents of Check->Time

Please do suggest how to solve this problem. I have lost(spent) around 10 hours and counting to resolve this issue, and tons of hair.

Soham

**EDIT** STRUCTURE DEF ADDED

Comment: Can you provide the code for initialization of `Check`?

Comment: Since you don't show us the crucial code - how `Check` is initialized - we can't tell you if you've done something wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using an address of the stack allocated object to initialize new_Message->Time  = &a[2][11];

Comment: Good point - and `new_Message->asset` too.  And it could explain why `Check->time` ends up with the same address as `new_Message->time`; the code that sets `Check->time` might be in a function that just happens to use the same address for its local storage as `parser()` used for its storage.

Comment: @Soham: strings in C have to be copied; pointers to local strings are dangerous. If you learned Java or Perl or Python first, they have real built-in strings; C doesn't. C has pointers; you have to take extreme care to make sure you know, at all times, where a string is allocated. You can't simply copy a pointer to a local variable to return a string to the caller. You have to take major steps to copy the data around - allocating (and then freeing) the space, or having the caller pass the space and the called function copy into that space. I think @ydroneaud has hit the core of your problem.

Comment: Yes, I think you have a point here. Yes, you are right. But then, how should I go about separating these two? Because, new_Message->Time is being assigned to another structure, called Order->EntryTime, and that at some point of time is being used to store into Check->Time; Yes, can you please suggest me how do I go about separating them? I.e I want to actually copy a string of variable length.

Comment: @Soham use strdup(). But be careful of memory leaks.

Comment: One way is to use a function `strdup()` to copy a string.  This is standard on POSIX systems (Linux, etc).  If it isn't available on yours, you can write one easily: `char *strdup(const char *str) { char *copy = malloc(strlen(str)+1); if (copy != 0) strcpy(copy, str); return(copy); }`.

Comment: Its very unfortunate that I can upvote you folks only once. Jon, its equally unfortunate that I can't tick your and ydroneaud's answers simultaneously. You two, have solved the problem in practically jiffy. Kudos to you folks. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Although you don't show us how you initialize `Check` which limits the amount of help we can give, there is an unnecessary parameter to `parse()` which you can remove.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Message *newMessage;
    Asset *Check;
    [...]
    newMessage = parser("N,2376...,0,0", newMessage);
    [...]
}

Message *parser(char *message, Message *new_Message)
{
    [...]
    new_Message = (Message *)malloc(sizeof(Message));
    [...]
    return(new_Message);
}
```

When you look at that skeleton, it may be easier to see that:

a. The value in `main()` passed to `parser()` as `newMessage` is undefined because the local variable has not been initialized, but

b. It doesn't matter much because the first thing that happens in `parser()` is that a value is allocated and assigned to the function's copy of the uninitialized value (`new_Message`), thus initializing the value used in `parser()`.

So, the code is 'safe', but could be written as:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Message *newMessage;
    Asset *Check;
    [...]
    newMessage = parser("N,2376...,0,0");
    [...]
}

Message *parser(char *message)
{
    [...]
    Message *new_Message = (Message *)malloc(sizeof(Message));
    [...]
    return(new_Message);
}
```

It is best not to pass values to functions that are not used.

Also, most people either use underscores to separate words in names or use `camelCase` names, but not usually `camel_Case` which combines both.

Comment: I have added the structure definitions.

Comment: @Soham: thanks for the structure definitions.  Unfortunately, they aren't as interesting as the code that manipulates `Check`.