# How to break on access of a specific global variable in gdb?

Tags: c, gdb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I set a breakpoint on 'memory access' in GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58851/can-i-set-a-breakpoint-on-memory-access-in-gdb)

I want to trace how a specific variable is initialized,

can gdb do this kind of job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gdb command `watch <expr>` sets a breakpoint on write, `rwatch` on read, and `awatch`  on read or write. You can use them as you would with breakpoints, with two considerations:

- You can't use gdb expressions in them (like `$esp+...`)
- You need support for them. Software support is much, much slower than hardware. To find out if your gdb can use hardware watchpoints, see the output of `show can-use-hw-watchpoints`.