# Can I have gdb break on read/write from an address?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, gdb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I set a breakpoint on 'memory access' in GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58851/can-i-set-a-breakpoint-on-memory-access-in-gdb)

I have a specific location in memory that is getting corrupted, and I'd like to be able to see exactly when things write to that location. Is there any way that I can make gdb break on memory access to that particular address?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**Yes.**
Using **Watchpoints**:
**watch** - only breaks on write (and only if the value changes)
**rwatch** -  breaks on read, and
**awatch** - breaks on read/write.

A more detailed brief from some internet sources:

***watch***
watch is gdb’s way of setting data breakpoints which will halt the execution of a program if memory changes at the specified location.

watch breakpoints can either be set on the variable name or any address location.

```
watch my_variable
watch *0x12345678
where 0x12345678 is a valid address.
```

***rwatch***
rwatch (read-watch) breakpoints break the execution of code when the program tries to read from a variable or memory location.

```
rwatch iWasAccessed
rwatch *0x12345678
where 0x12345678 is a valid address.
```

***awatch***
awatch or access watches break execution of the program if a variable or memory location is written to or read from. In summary, awatches are watches and rwatches all in one. It is a handy way of creating one breakpoint than two separate ones.

```
awatch *0x12345678
where 0x12345678 is a valid address.
```

Comment: Somehow you're writing `×` in place of `x`...

Comment: @Alok How to differ when using `awatch` between break due to read or write?

Comment: Is there any way to watch a large region of memory (several words wide)?

Comment: @Alok what is the equivalent command for awatch or rwatch in lldb?