# How to add a Break point on memory location in gdb

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, gdb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I set a breakpoint on 'memory access' in GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58851/can-i-set-a-breakpoint-on-memory-access-in-gdb)

I am mainly working on Windows and using Visual Studio as debugger, it provide the functionality to add a  break point on memory location. Whenever that memory changed it stop the execution. 
Anyone, know same kind of functionality in gdb on Linux.

Answer (score 3):

The manual section called ["Setting Watchpoints"](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html#Set-Watchpoints) is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, such functionality is called [Watchpoints](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html) in gdb