# How to find the code that creates a memory address in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am trying to find the source code that causes some leaks reported in Instruments, but all I get is the Address. Is there a way to take this Address, or use some other feature in Instruments, to then locate where the offending object is located in the actual source code?

Comment: Are you also getting leaks reported, when you run Product => Analyze (from the Xcode menu)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this contains the answer to your question (although it's not a 'duplicate question').

[Can I set a breakpoint on 'memory access' in GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58851/can-i-set-a-breakpoint-on-memory-access-in-gdb)

Comment: Thanks but it is unclear to me how I would use rwatch in an Xcode breakpoint... Also is the hex memory address always going to be the same every time I run the app?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that you said that the memory address was the same each time.

Comment: Good luck sorting your problem!