# Checking when a variable is modified

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gcc, x86

Using Valgrind or any other debugger in Linux, how can one see places where a variable is modified. I am using gcc. Note that I don't want to step into the code using gdb. I just want to run the program and have the debugger report me in the end, places where the variable is modified in the code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I set a breakpoint on 'memory access' in GDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58851/can-i-set-a-breakpoint-on-memory-access-in-gdb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Breakpoint Command Lists](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Break-Commands.html#Break-Commands) to do this in gdb. You will have to know the address of variable to watch. Set watchpoint with a series of commands like this:

> ```
>  watch *0xfeedface
>  commands
>  silent
>  bt
>  cont
>  end
> ```

You can also optionally save all this output to log file. Look [gdb doc](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Logging-Output.html) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Hm, thinking about it it's not *exact* duplicate of [Can I set a breakpoint on 'memory access' in GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58851/can-i-set-a-breakpoint-on-memory-access-in-gdb), because it asks a little bit more. So:

1. Use gdb
2. Find the address you want to watch (hardware watchpoints only work for watching *address*, so you have to run it to the point where the variable or object are instantiated, take their address and use the `watch` command on that address.
3. Attach command to the address to give you a backtrace (or any other info you need to collect) and continue.

So you'll have something like:

```
p &variable
watch *$$
cmd
bt
c
end
```

(I am not completely sure with the `$$`, I normally use the `$n` as printed by the `p` command).

Comment: If the variable is modified in many places (say, in a tight loop) this will be *unbearably* slow. I would say only use this method if it's your last resort.

Comment: It is not that slow, assuming you want to follow the variable's changes, because the watchpoint above is usually a hardware watchpoint. Software watchpoints (for example, watching t[i]) are considerably slower...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: If you add `cmd/bt/c/end`, it *will* be slow. It's the printing of backtraces that slows it down, not the watchpoint.

Comment: Agreed. So it depends if the variable changes very often or not.