# gdb break on read/write from an address in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gdb

There is about how to set breakpoint on memory read/write:

[Can I set a breakpoint on 'memory access' in GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58851/can-i-set-a-breakpoint-on-memory-access-in-gdb)

How to perform that in Eclipse debugging window?
I need to do that while debugging C/C++ project for Cortex-M microcontrollers.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a read breakpoint in gdb using the `rwatch` command.  See `help rwatch` for details.  Note that it is often very slow.

I don't know how to do this from Eclipse.