# Can the code of some C++ class accidentally overwrite a private static variable of another class?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, private-members

I mean a scenario like this: There is some class (I call it `victim`) with a private data member and another class (named `attacker`) with some method, which, of course, normally does not have access to private members of other classes and does not even hold a reference to an instance of `victim`:

```
extern "C" {
#include <pigpiod_if2.h>
}

class victim {
private:
  static bool is_ready;
  static bool is_on;
public:
  static void init ()
    {
       is_ready = true;
       is_on    = true;
    }

  /* Some other public methods go here. */
}

class attacker {
private:
  static int last_read_pin;
public:
  static void run ()
  {
    while (true) {
      /* Some sensible code goes here. */
      last_read_pin = -1;
      time_sleep (0.01); // Using nanosleep () does not change behavior.
    }
  }
}
```

This is just a code snippet to illustrate the following question: Is it possible, not just in theory, but also practically, that `attacker::run ()` can modify the values of the two private static vars of `victim` unintentionally, without addressing any public member of `victim`, maybe due to undefined behavior or even a compiler bug? Thank you.

**UPDATE:** After a hint from another user, I did rebuild the complete app using `make clean` and `make`. Also, I added the endless loop into my example. The change in `is_ready` occurs during the sixth run of the loop. Changing the sleep interval does not change behavior, though.

**UPDATE #2:** I ran my code through `gdb` with a watch on the `is_ready` variable, and I got an alert when `last_read_pin` was set to –1:

```
Hardware watchpoint 1: is_ready

Old value = true
New value = false
attacker::Run ()
last_read_pin       = -1;
```

**UPDATE #3:** Moving `last_read_pin` into the `Run ()` method itself, thereby making it an internal variable, does not help either.

**UPDATE #4:** After simply commenting out the line of code, which makes so much trouble, the issue still persisten, apparently being caused by one line above, which reads like this:

`keypad::last_levels [h] [k] =  0;`

I had to comment out this line, too, to get rid of the problem with `is_ready` being changed.

Could the use of `pigpiod` cause this issue? I an earlier version, I was using `pigpio` directly and did not encounter this problem.

Compiled with gcc 4.9.2.

Comment: Yes, anything is possible with undefined behavior.

Comment: I am pretty sure you can abuse the language to do this *on purpose* (aka it's very obvious when you do it), I don't exactly recall how though. Maybe you are reading uninitialized memory (likely), corrupting the object memory (less likely) or encountering just another sort of weirdness in your real usecase - assuming your question is related to a real problem in a larger codebase.

Comment: The private mechanism in C++ isn't a security system, and can be pretty trivially be got around. However, it's unlikely (though not impossible) that you can modify private member variables unintentionally.

Comment: @asu: Yes, my particular use case is about a much larger piece of code I can't post here for some reason. But: I do initialise my variables properly before running the run () method.

Comment: Easy to do with a versioning problem.  Old non-recompiled code uses a new class that is bigger.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I issued `make clean` before compiling. Doesn't this suffice?

Comment: Note that `private`/`public` is a red herring here. The point is that somebody writes where they are not supposed to. Eben a plain global variable's memory is only supposed to be accessed *through that variable* (and, if present, aliases), not through unrelated memory references (arrays, pointers). Such memory corruption is very easy to do in C/C++ and notoriously hard to find.

Comment: OK, for myself, I am neither using the two variables in question in an array, nor am I using any pointers to them.

Comment: @Neppomuk I guessed that much ;-). Some other pointer points there. With [gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58851/can-i-set-a-breakpoint-on-memory-access-in-gdb) or Visual C++ you can break when a particular address gets written to; that should give you a hint. (Oh, I see that you updated your question and did that already :-) ).

Comment: If code like this leads to behaviour like you describe, you are most likely dealing with either a compiler bug or a hardware bug. Though one cannot exclude UB that occurs elsewhere weirdly interacting with this code. Another pissibility is gdb misidentifying the offending line. It is really hard to tell without seeing the whole picture.

Answer (score 0):

After floating around the code line in question, I found out that the blunder was lying **in the line before**, which reads as follows:

```
last_levels [h] [l] = 0;
```

Unfortunately, `h` can be < 0. In this case, some kinda exception (array index out of bounds) should be thrown, but unfortunately, it isn't (Does anybody know why?). The gdb gave me the wrong information of the overwrite of  `is_ready` to happen in the following line (Is this maybe a bug?), and I believed this without any criticism. As if this wasn't enough, this error made no problems until I changed my code in a completely different place!

This blunder has cost me quite much time, but now, at last, I know what its cause was, and I corrected it successfully. Thank you anyway for your hints and comments!