# How to hook memory I/O in windows kernel mode?

Tags: c, windows, memory, kernel

(English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.)
I tried to monitor memory I/O on Windows. An apparent way is to poll some memory address like this:

```
while(true)
{
    ::ReadProcessMemory(...);
    if (changed)
        call back;
}
```

but that make some overhead. So I want to install a hook to monitor memory I/O(Maybe I need to write code in the ring0). But I can't find any information about that(on google, on msdn, etc.).
Can I do that? How to?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/58851/1216776

Comment: @stark how does that have anything to do with Windows?

Comment: @stark the watchpoint in gdb has 2 ways to implement: software watchpoint, like my example code; Hardware watchpoint, which using the debugging register.It's only for debugging.